# competitve network type from matlab in python

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, classification

I want to create a network in python that has similar effect as competitve network type in matlab.

- Screenshot from instruction how to define competitive in nntool.
  [image]
- [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/competitive-learning.html) to matlab example

Is there alternative in python frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of **competitve network type** can be used SOM (Self-Organized map - Kohonem map).

I used [this neupy](http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.competitive.sofm.html) implementation

---

Here is **example** copied from linked site:

```py
import numpy as np
from neupy import algorithms, utils

utils.reproducible()

data = np.array([
    [0.1961, 0.9806],
    [-0.1961, 0.9806],
    [-0.5812, -0.8137],
    [-0.8137, -0.5812],
])

sofm = algorithms.SOFM(
    n_inputs=2,
    n_outputs=2,
    step=0.1,
    learning_radius=0
)
sofm.train(data, epochs=100)
sofm.predict(data)
```